# Cyrillic characters show as gibberish in rhythmbox

Tags: keyboard, music, utf-8, id3

I have some Bulgarian/Russian songs which have Cyrillic characters in them. Nautilus displays them fine , but in rhythmbox all their id3tag info is displayed as gibberish.

I have set the system language to Russian(UTF-8) .

Downloaded some program named mp3diags with which I tried to convert id3 tags to utf-8 but instead of gibberish the song was displayed  with Chinese letters.

I tried to use EasyTag , but could not find out how to mass rename song titles or to convert them to UTF-8.

P.S There are some songs which are displayed right in rhythmbox (i.e I can see the artist name , album , song title just fine - all written in Cyrillic) , does that mean that the problem is in my Songs?
If someone has faced similar problem I would be most grateful for some info on solving it.

Comment: There is a related bug, which might have a bit to do with this. It has been fixed now https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/992154

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common problem with Cyrillic id3tags encoded in Windows.

There is a python script, [tag2utf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tag2utf/files/), you could try to fix the encoding.

Just place the script into the same folder where the songs are, run it with `python ./tag2utf-0.16.py`, and follow the prompt.

Reportedly, there is also another tool, mid3iconv. It is part of the `python-mutagen` package in the repositories.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I stumbled on the same script while searching on google , but had no idea how to execute it. Now Rhythmbox recognizes all the songs.

Comment: That is an awesome script.  Works great!  Just have to select 'c' for every prompt.  I wish it did that recursively.

Comment: @IgorG. Remove 2nd pair from `charsets = {'cp1251':'c','koi8-r':'k' }` and you are done

Comment: Thank you very much this worked perfectly for me as well. I had to install the python-eyed3 package in Ubuntu 15.04 but the script was perfect. :)